# how to redirect from http to https and delete www with subdomain in laravel 7

Tags: laravel, .htaccess, laravel-7

I have a subdomain.

I want to redirect all links to one link. And enable https and delete www from.

For example:

I want redirect all this links:

- `https://www.blog.example.com`
- `https://blog.example.com`
- `http://www.blog.example.com`
- `http://blog.example.com`

to:

- `https://blog.example.com`

This is my .htaccess file:

```
Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=86400; includeSubDomains;" env=HTTPS

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews -Indexes
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

<IfModule mime_module>
  AddHandler application/x-httpd-ea-php74 .php .php7 .phtml
</IfModule>
```

Comment: But all listed subdomains are running same laravel app?

Comment: This is is a DNS issue,  Do it with with DNS

Comment: @EsTeAa You can't "redirect" with DNS.

Comment: @MrWhite you can redirect with DNS. the sub-domain call with the DNS first

Comment: @EsTeAa That's not a "redirect", as in an "HTTP external redirect" - which is what is being asked in the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a laravel specific issue. You have to edit your .htaccess file. Add the following code to your .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: You are missing the `[R=301,L]` flags on the first rule.

Comment: please what you mean?

Comment: i added the code in the .htaccess.

but when i go to this url: https://www.blog.error-sd.com/login Or any other url with www

it redirect me to this url: https://blog.error-sd.com/index.php

Comment: another example this link: https://www.blog.error-sd.com/article/user-full-guide-for-laravel-mix-91

redirect me to this: https://blog.error-sd.com/index.php

Comment: @HasanHatem You are putting the directives in the wrong place, they need to go at the top of the `.htaccess` file, before your existing rewrites. (And as mentioned in my comment above, the first rule is missing the required _flags_ argument.)

Comment: This code did not solve the problem.
I added the .htaccess code in the TOP.
@MrWhite

Comment: @yun_jay I added your code but still have the same problem.
I put the .htaccess in public folder.
I added my .htaccess file code in the Top.

Comment: @HasanHatem "I added the .htaccess code in the TOP" - But in the code you've added to your question ("my .htaccess file") you've put the code at the _bottom_, not at the top?!

Comment: @MrWhite Yes yes yes thank you very much it has been resolved